# Ascendancy ships not availible

Tags: ascendancy

I recently picked up an old copy of Ascendancy for DOS (Installed DOSBox to play it). However, As I got farther into the game, I realized I was falling WAY behind in the amount of ships I had, as compared to the AIs. So I go to a planet with open population, but I can't build a ship (and I already have some ships built, so [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/how-do-i-build-a-ship-in-ascendancy) doesn't help). I try to build ships on other available planets (free population, a shipyard, and an open space in orbit around the planet), but none of those work either. Am I missing a prerequisite for shipbuilding? I have the most number of colonies, so I know it's not that, but I'm wondering (and something in the back of my head says this is true) if I need to have control of more systems or some other requirement. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Ship Building](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/575213-ascendancy/faqs/35315):

> Each colonized 
>   system you control grants you the ability to have 1 ship, and your home system
>   lets you have 2. You must have all the planets in a system colonized to have
>   a ship slot. Thus if your home system has 3 planets, and you you have all 3
>   colonized, you have the ability to build up to 2 ships (providing you have 
>   Docks which you can build with). If you have 3 systems entirely colonized, you
>   can build up to 4 ships (2+1+1).

Check count of systems you have colonized.

Comment: ohhh... ALL the planets in a system. Whoops. Ok thanks that's exactly what I was missing. Thanks! Now, off to start colonizing planets!